# How to use the filter function to see if a time is in a certain time frame?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am trying to see if my current hour is in any of the given time frames and if it is, print out the name.

Right now, I have an array of objects that have a name and a time frame. For example,

```js
theArray = [
  {Name:'Medicine', Time: '3 PM - 11 PM'},
  {Name:'Sleep', Time: '10 AM - 3 PM'}
]
```

Both Name and Time are strings. I am trying to get my code to do something like this: If my current time is 4PM, the program would print out Medicine.

I tried to do this in render():

```js
 <div>
    { 
      this.state.theArray.filter(testing => parseInt((testing["Time"]).slice(1,1)) <= myHour && parseInt((testing["Time"]).slice(7,7)) >= myHour).map(x => (
      <li>
        {x.Name} <br />
      </li> ))
    }
</div>
```

However, it doesn't print anything and I realize I did not consider the "AM" and "PM" part of the time.

Would anyone be able to help or give me a hint on how to approach this?

Comment: The best approach would be a cleaner data structure. Have you any way to go back to the server and modify the data to output ISO-formatted start and end times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enough to meet your needs

```js
const theArray = [
  { Name: 'Medicine', Time: '3 PM - 11 PM' },
  { Name: 'Sleep', Time: '10 AM - 3 PM' }
]

function getTime(theArray) {
  const nowTime = new Date().getHours();
  let output = '';
  theArray.map(item => {
    const arr = item.Time.split(' ');
    const time1 = arr[1] === 'PM' ? 12 : 0;
    const time2 = arr[4] === 'PM' ? 12 : 0;
    if (nowTime > (+arr[0] + time1) && nowTime < (+arr[3] + time2)) {
      output = item.Name
    };
  })
  return output;
}

console.log(getTime(theArray))
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! It was easy to understand and very efficient. It helped so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would refactor your API or input so that the start and end times are given as two separate DateTime objects, which would let you do this much more easily.

However, given your current input format, you can split the time-strings with a dash, then for each of them, then split again by the space add 12 hours depending am or pm, to get your two times.
You can then compare this to the current hour to find the activity, and output the name.

```js
const theArray = [{
    Name: 'Medicine',
    Time: '3 PM - 11 PM'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Sleep',
    Time: '10 AM - 3 PM'
  }
]

const get24HourTimes = (timeString) => timeString.split(' - ').map(timeStr => parseInt(timeStr.split(' ')[0]) + (timeStr.split(' ')[1] == "PM" ? 12 : 0))

const currentHour = new Date().getHours();

const currentActivity = theArray.find(item => {
  const [startTime, endTime] = get24HourTimes(item.Time);
  return currentHour >= startTime && currentHour < endTime 
}).Name

console.log(currentActivity)
```

Answer (score 1):

The draft way:

```
const theArray = [
  {Name:'Medicine', Time: '3 PM - 11 PM'},
  {Name:'Sleep', Time: '10 AM - 3 PM'}
];

for(let i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
  // Split time
  let [start, end] = theArray[i].Time.split('-');

  // Parse start time
  start = start.replace(/^\s*(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s*/, (str, num, ampm) => {
    ampm = (ampm === 'PM') ? 12 : 0;
    return Number(num)+ampm;
  });
  // Parse end time
  end = end.replace(/^\s*(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s*/, (str, num, ampm) => {
    ampm = (ampm === 'PM') ? 12 : 0;
    return Number(num)+ampm;
  });
  
  // Check time
  const d = new Date();
  const hr = d.getHours();
  
  if(start <= hr && end >= hr) console.log(`${theArray[i].Name}: Alarm!`);
}
```

Example [is here](https://jsbin.com/vaneguh/9/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Given the equivalent javascript code you can convert this to react easily.
Find the logical code below.

```js
var theArray = [{
    Name: 'Medicine',
    Time: '3 PM - 11 PM'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Sleep',
    Time: '10 AM - 3 PM'
  }
];
var currentTime = 16; // this time should be in 24 hour format.

var matchedActivity = this.theArray.find(testing => {
  var timeArray = testing["Time"].split(' - ');
  
  var startTime = timeArray[0].indexOf('PM') > -1 ? parseInt(timeArray[0]) + 12 : parseInt(timeArray[0]);
  var endTime = timeArray[1].indexOf('PM') > -1 ? parseInt(timeArray[1]) + 12 : parseInt(timeArray[1]); 

  return currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime;
});
console.log(matchedActivity.Name)
```

Comment: @webdesignnoob hope this will solve your problem. Thanks.